# Java library to support dates with limited precision (like year/month only)

Tags: java, date

In some system I have to operate on dates which may have limited precission (like month and year only or year only), e.g. "2001" or "January 2011". I need to know not only date, but the presission (day, month or year) as well.

I can do this by hand, but does anybody know any java library which supports this type of dates with variable precission?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a well known library such as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and model each "date" as a time span (`Interval` in Joda Time).

After all, that's sort of what it is; "2001" is not actually a specific point in time, but a period.

The span / length of the interval would reveal the precision, and the starting point of the period could be interpreted as the point in time at which the "date occurred".

Comment: It's not a period in the Joda sense ("2 months" or "3 week") - it's a partial, like `YearMonth`, `LocalDate` etc.

Comment: Aha. Not very experienced with the library. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. These both classes should be sufficient for your use case.

Reference: [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Yep, but this is what I mean by 'by hand' - create class which has precision and date, and define all operations, using Calendar/Date/SimpleDateFormat. But before start I wanted to check - maybe someone did it already, and there is a good standard solution?

Answer (score 0):

why not use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class ?

Comment: Given a Calendar instance, there's no indication of what precision the value held has.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which already has support for a [`YearMonth`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) type (amongst other things) - you can create your own `Year` type if you want, based on similar code.